# Links not resolved correctly when using relative paths

Tags: php, html

I've created a `Header.php` file in the root directory.

Below is the tree structure.

```
-SiteName
  -Header.php
  -Books
    -Samples
      -Math
        -MathBook.php
 -index.php
 -About.php
```

So MathBook.php includes Header.php like below

```
include '../../../Header.php';
```

Header.php is included in About.php like this

```
include 'Header.php';
```

Now Header.php contains the code for the navigation menu.

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="index.php" class="<?php active('index.php');?>">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.php" class="<?php active('AboutUs.php');?>">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

So now when I'm in Math.php and I press home it takes me to:

```
/Books/Samples/Math/index.php
```

Obviously the URL doesn't exist.

How i can make sure when the user is in Math.php it should go to `index.php` without including current path.

Header.php is included in all files.

Comment: Use root-relative urls for links. `<a href="/index.php" class="<?php active('index.php');?>">Home</a>` or `<a href="/About.php" class="<?php active('AboutUs.php');?>">About Us</a>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a **relative path**.

by typing "index.php" in the href attribute, you are pointing to a file named "index.php" in the current folder.

If you want to point to a file in the root folder, you need to use a slash `/`

```
href="/<sub folder if any>/index.php"
href="/<sub folder if any>/About.php"
```

This will take the user to the file you would like, also if you are unsure about what to use, just use absolute paths like this:

```
href="https://www.example.com/<sub folder if any>/index.php"
href="https://www.example.com/<sub folder if any>/About.php"
```

**EDIT**

Adding a slash works because by adding `/` you tell the browser to go to the root folder/website and start the path from there.

Let's say you are in `yourwebsite.com/current/path/file.html`.

A link to `/some/path/to/a-file.php` resolves to `yourwebsite.com/some/path/to/a-file.php`

But a link to `some/path/to/a-file.php` resolves to `yourwebsite.com/current/path/some/path/to/a-file.php`

Comment: I don't want to use absolute path.If use /index then it take me root of server.My site is some folder under server root

Comment: You can simply add the sub-folder to the path, see updated question.

Comment: I added a simple explanation see updated answer, and to the down voter an explanation is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You could define includes and links relative to your site's base url.

The hrefs can be written like so:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <a 
      href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php';?>" 
      class="<?php active('index.php');?>">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a 
     href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/About.php';?>" 
     class="<?php active('AboutUs.php');?>">About Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think OP has a problem with links and not the `include` part, btw the downvote is not mine

Comment: OP's problem is about the links not about the include part, contrary to what it says in title.